# Passing form search submit data to redirected results page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a search page that uses an AJAX (WordPress) form to filter results. Let's say `results.php` for the example.

What I would like to do is use the same form on another page `home.php` but upon submit will redirect to the `results.php` search page with it's results (into `#response`). What would be the best way to pass and redirect form data to the AJAX results page?

**AJAX FORM**

```
$('#filter').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var filter = $('#filter');

    $.ajax({
        url: filter.attr('action'),
        data:filter.serialize(),
        type: 'POST', // POST
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {   
        $('#response').html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;

});
```

**FORM**

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"     method="POST" id="filter">

   <input id="address" name="property_location" placeholder="Input Address" type="text"/>

   <button type="submit"  id="filter">Search</button>

   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_search"> //my_search taken from ajax function query.

</form>
```

Comment: The usefullness of Ajax is to reload a part of the page **without** having a redirect. If you want a redirect any way... I think would should not use ajax. Just post the data to `result.php`. --- I may not have understood correctly your question... But my feeling is that you want to ride a car and a truck at the same time.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I know it seems a strange request but essentially I'd like to be able to have the benefits of AJAX results but also be able to use the same form on the homepage (Property listing site) to direct to the AJAX page. Even if there was a way to save out the form data on homepage submit and input into the response div of results page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're redirecting the page when the form is submitted, then there's no need to pass values back to home.php and then redirect.

You can still use AJAX to submit but do the redirect from the PHP side. Keep the AJAX though in case there is an error you need to inform the user about.

So in the PHP file you're submitting to, don't echo anything back, just redirect. If there's an error, then send back whatever is appropriate for the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So would it still be possible to output the form results with `action="/results.php` and return it into the `response div` of the `results.php` page?

Comment: Sure, you might need to save the data you want to pass on as $_SESSION variables so you can read them in to your #response div. There are different ways of processing that depending on your needs. As as an example though:
`<div ="response">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['some_variable'];?>">
</div>`

Comment: Okay great. You don't think there would be a way to send the form on `home.php` using the conventional `action` then inputting that into the AJAX request? Both are using the same `#filter` form. It would save having to use 2 separate parts of code :)

Comment: You could skip ajax altogether and just reload the page with an error message if not successful.

Comment: You're welcome. An up vote and/or Solved would be appreciated. ;)